# Is there a feasible workaround for Leica M Monochrom DNG files with Apple aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture, dng, leica

So far Aperture does not support Leica M Monochrom DNG's and the best way I have found to get the files into Aperture is to open the DNG's up in Adobe DNG, export them as TIFFs and import the TIFFs into Aperture. This does the job I suppose in a round about clunky way, but you obviously lose DNG control inside Aperture.
If anyone knows a better way I would be most grateful.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Lightroom? It sells for only about $80. Scott Borne has a set of postings about switching, moving your library, etc. I followed them with good luck. I liked Aperture's workflow better, but got tired of Apple's slow release schedule.

Comment: Yeah been there with Lightroom. The workflow is a bit backward and once you're in the only way to export your entire library back out is using Jpegs. Apple is slow with updates but I much prefer the whole Aperture interface so I'm going to stick with it right now. Thanks though!

Comment: No interest in starting a LR vs Aper discussion. I too prefer the Aperture workflow. I just prefer the LR features a tiny bit more. Lens correction is a great ability -- maybe not as important with Leica lenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, Aperture now [supports Leica M Monochrom DNGs](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2013/08/23/apple-raw-compatibility-update-adds-support-for-canon-70d-and-more?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=news-list&utm_medium=text&ref=title_0_29)!

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a work around using [Adobe DNG Converter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5568).  I don't have a Mac to try it on, but it can convert many DNGs to a more generic type.

Comment: Did this actually work? It seems like a long shot to me, since the files are _already_ DNG.

Comment: yes. i converted them to an older version of dng and turned of linear in custom settings and it went in and retained the raw editing features. it's still not ideal, but it's better :)

Comment: I just tried this with a new batch of shots (replicated the above) and it did not work this time. I can't understand why that would have happened...